# Scrape result export prooblem

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have written a simple spider to search details on a website. When I run it on the console I'm getting the output, but if I put it into a file using `-o filename.json` it is just giving me a `[` in the file. What do I do?

My spider looks like

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class ChillumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "chillum"
allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=brown+jacket&as=offas-show=off&otracker=start"]

def parse(self, response):
    title=response.xpath('//a[@class="fk-display-block"]/text()').extract()
    print title
```

And my output on the console looks like

> [u"\n Asst JKT8810 Full Sleeve Self Design Men's Cotton ", u' ', u"\n
>   Justanned Full Sleeve Solid Men's Bomber ", u' ', u"\n Pepe Sleeveless
>   Solid Men's ", u' ', u"\n Platinum Studio Sleeveless Solid Men's Nehru
>   ", u' ', u"\n Yepme Sleevele ss Solid Men's ", u' ', u'\n Love Leather
>   ', u" Full Sleeve Solid Men's Puleather Ja...\n ", u"\n Justanned Full
>   Sleeve Solid Men's Bomber ", u' ', u"\n Oceanic Full Sleeve Self
>   Design Men's ", u' ', u"\n Dooda Full Sleeve Solid Men's ", u'  ',
>   u"\n Bare Skin Full Sleeve Self Design Men's ", u' ', u"\n Asst Full
>   Sleeve Solid Women's ", u' ', u"\n Locomotive F ull Sleeve Men's ", u'
>   ', u"\n Justanned Full Sleeve Solid Women's Leather ", u' ', u' ',
>   u"\n Wrangler Sleeveless Solid  Men's ", u' ', u"\n TSX Sleeveless
>   Solid Men's Bomber ", u' ']

But when I do `scrapy crawl spider_name -o filename.json` I'm not getting the same output in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need to return [`Item`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) instances:

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class ChillumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "chillum"
    allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=brown+jacket&as=offas-show=off&otracker=start"]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath('//a[@class="fk-display-block"]/text()').extract()
        for title in titles:
            item = TutorialItem()
            item['title'] = title
            yield item
```